# Trouble Setting Frames of NSView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have no idea why this code isn't working, but hopefully the fix is simple, I hope someone can help.

I have 2 functions, enterFullScreen and exitFullScreen.

In the enterFullScreen method, I set an NSView's frame to the Window's frame, which has a full-screen effect, this is what I want. Within this method I store the old frames so that in the exitFullScreen method I can set them back, but this isn't working. It has no effect whatsoever. The code is as follows:

```
NSView oldView, oldViewContainer;

- (void) enterFullScreen:(NSView*)newView
{
    // Store original views
    oldView = newView;
    oldViewContainer = _newViewContainer;

    // Set new views to fit window
    [_newViewContainer setFrame:[_window.contentView frame]];    
    [newView setFrame:[_window.contentView frame]];
}

- (void) exitFullScreen:(NSView*)newView
{
    // Restore old views
    [_newViewContainer setFrame:[oldViewContainer frame]];
    [newView setFrame:[oldView frame]];
}
```

The enter fullscreen method works exactly as expected, but for some reason I can't set the 2 Views back to their original size/location.

I don't know if it's because I can't just store the whole view, or if the origin is causing problems?

I've tried every combination, if somebody could help I'd be really grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to set oldView to newView, that makes them the same view, so when you resize newView to full screen, oldView's frame also is set to full screen.  You want to save the old frame, not the view, so:
oldFrame = newView.frame; (to store the original frame)

then when you resize smaller,

[newView setFrame:oldFrame];

Comment: thanks for the answer, but if you have your window, and the newView and the frame is a specific size, and you store the frame. When you resize the view and everything resizes, and you set the frame to the old one, it'll be the wrong size?

Comment: I think I answered this in a another one of your questions -- you need to deal with it in the window delegation method windowDidResize: This will be called after you resize your window, so you can change oldFrame inside that method to whatever is appropriate.

Comment: Yeah sorry I wasn't expecting the same answer for 2 problems. Adding code to change variables in a didResize method would be very processor intensive. For now I've put custom views over the old ones as placeholders and use their frames when setting back to old size, this works perfectly, even though it's not the cleanest thing.